# Acumatica and Dashboard Parameters and Selector and PKID

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to have a parameter that has a selector option to popup a list of users. When selected, we want the PKID to populate the parameter field. We will then use that parameter field in all of the widget filters.

I'm not able to find any schema object/fields that produce the desired end result.

We tried OwnerID from CROpportunity to no avail.

[image]

We are trying to achieve a selector control to show PKID and Username in selector popup, and upon selecting value, PKID should go as input field and show the result. For this I have created a unbound field in Users DAC and wrote selector for it.

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Associate")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Users.pKID>), new Type[] { typeof(Users.pKID), typeof(Users.displayName) },
            SubstituteKey = typeof(Users.pKID), DescriptionField = typeof(Users.displayName))]
public virtual Guid? UsrKWInput { get; set; }
public abstract class usrKWInput : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<usrKWInput> { }
```

With above code I am getting what I need in selector popup, but after selecting value am getting error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be identifying exactly what you want to show in the selector.

> We are trying to have a parameter that has a selector option to popup
>   a list of users

I understand this as the `UserList` data view in `Users` page (SM201010).

The selector field in that data view is `Users.Username`:

```
    public abstract class username : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<username> { }
    protected string _username;

    [PXDBString(64, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Login", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Users.username, Where<Users.isHidden, Equal<False>>>))]
    [PXFieldDescription]
    public virtual String Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value != null ? value.Trim() : null; }
    }
```

EDIT:
To persist PKID in database and show both PKID and DisplayName in the selector try this:

```
[PXDBGuid]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "User", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Users.pKID, Where<Users.isHidden, Equal<False>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(Users.displayName))]
[PXFieldDescription]
public virtual Guid? UsrUser { get; set; }
public abstract class usrUser : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<usrUser> { }
```

Result on screen:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for input.i have updated my question, can you please check it